# How to print a point in a 3D plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Given set of `points` with every point 3-dimensional.
From the beggining of my code i used

```
        import numpy as np
        from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
        plt.plot(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], points[:, 2], 'o')
```

and drown 3D plot. After my program work i found one more point called `result` that i want to add to my plot [with red color].
I haven't used `plt.show()` yet.

So then i use `plt.plot(result[0], result[1], result[2], 'ro')` and `plt.show()` after this all.

But it is not working like first time i used `plot()`.

And i have an error:

> File "< input >", line 3, in < module >
>
> File "file path" in plot is not None else {}), **kwargs)
>
> in plot zs = np.broadcast_to(zs, len(xs))
>
> TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()

Help me, please. How can i correctly add one point to the plot?

Comment: Try `plt.plot([result[0]], [result[1]], [result[2]], 'ro')`

Comment: @QuangHoang, yes, it is working now, thanks. Seems that i need to use every time lists in `plot()`